# Locking Entire file using LockFileEx API in Windows

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, visual-c++

It is possible to do lock particular offset using [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx) API in windows using C++, I tried this and i got successful result.

But I tried to lock entire file using [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx), I failed to do. i didn't found any document on website how to do full file locking using LockfileEX.

```
    ifile = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);

    if (ifile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("CreateFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    OVERLAPPED overlapvar;
    overlapvar.Offset = 0; 
    overlapvar.OffsetHigh = 0;

    success = LockFileEx(ifile, LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK | LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY, 0, 0, 0, &overlapvar);
```

I tried with above code in windows but it is not taking lock on entire file. In my windows code i gave `overlapvar.Offset = 0` to say start of the file and `5th argument of LockFileEx to 0` to lock till end of the file.

I tried the same method in **linux** using **fcntl** like below.

```
struct  flock   param ;
param.l_type = F_RDLCK ;
param.l_whence = 0 ;
param.l_start = 0 ; //start of the file
param.l_len = 0 ; // 0 means end of the file

fcntl(FileFd, F_SETLKW, &param)
```

based on the two variable `param.l_start` and `param.l_len` we used to decide on which offset to take the lock. by setting these two variable to **0** help us to take lock from file starting to end in **Linux**.

I expecting same behaviour in Windows using [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx) or any other API.

*Is it possible to do full file lock in windows using LockFileEx ?*

*Is there any other API available to do full file lock ?*

*Is there any other method to do the same in windows?*

Thanks.

Comment: Stop expecting identical behavior for magic values.  `LockFileEx` provides approximately the same capability on Windows as `fcntl(F_SETLW)` does on Linux, but you can't blindly pass the same parameters.  You wouldn't Windows to understand `F_RDLCK` as a flag, why do you expect the "length 0 is magic and means the whole file" to work?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you unconditionally want to lock the entire contents of the file immediately after opening it. If that's the case, then you should simply pass `0` (no sharing) as the third argument to `CreateFile` instead of using `LockFileEx`.

Regarding `LockFileEx` usage in particular, you are locking a region starting at offset 0 (though the `OVERLAPPED` argument) and of length 0 (through the preceding two parameters). You can't specify "until end of file" for the length of the region by using zeroes. If you wanted to lock a region that spans the entire file you would simply specify both as `MAXDWORD`.

Comment: Thanks @Jon . Code which i given just the example. I need the function to lock and unlock, because other process expecting this file and will take the lock. And i can't change the because wrapper writtern over CreateFile it was used by many other function

Comment: @sujin: It's hard to tell why that happens without lots of additional information.

Comment: @sujin: The starting offset shouldn't be `MAXDWORD`, only the length.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation explicitly tells you that the `hEvent` member of the OVERLAPPED structure must be valid.  And OVERLAPPED doc says

> Any unused members of this structure should always be initialized to zero before the structure is used in a function call. Otherwise, the function may fail and return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Why are you passing uninitialized structures to API functions?  Try initializing `overlapvar` properly:

```
OVERLAPPED overlapvar = { 0 };

success = LockFileEx(ifile, LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK | LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY,
                            0, MAXDWORD, MAXDWORD, &overlapvar);
```